# How to combine equations that are describing related physical phenomena?

Tags: systems-of-equations, graphing-functions, projective-geometry

A quick word about what is going on to put this question in perspective. I am trying to dock a robot onto a charger.

[image]

Sometimes the robot center is not in line with the charger center. Let's call this offset "centering error". A centering error that is larger than 2cm will not allow the robot to dock properly. For this reason knowing the "centering error" is very important for me.

[image]

The charger has a QR Barcode, that the robot takes a picture of and processes. This yields a lot of data, such as area of barcode, barcode edge lengths, center point coordinate of barcode in image, etc... I hope you know a bit about how computers store images, and that pixels have x and y coordinates.
[image]

I am trying to merge mathematical relationships that represent existing physical relationships. I plotted key data, and matched it with suitable equations. Here are relationships  I have “found”:

**Relationship #1**
The amount of area occupied by the barcode in the image is correlated to the distance between the robot and the charger. This relationship is shown in the graph below. The X axis shows the distance, and the Y axis shows the area of the barcode. For graph and equation see: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oebhjbtp4q and shown below:
[image]

**Relationship #2**
If the robot is exactly 30 cm away from the charger (Let's assume this to be a fixed, unchanging truth of Relationship #2). I have established a line equation between the "centering error" and the center pixel of the barcode relative to the image the camera is getting. In the graph below, the Y axis is the "centering error" in centimeters, and the X axis is the X value (of an x and y pair) of the center pixel of the barcode (center pixel has an x and y coordinate in the image.. just like all pixels in the image have an x and y coordinate). So, if robot is EXACTLY 30cm away from panel (and robot is square to charger AND Camera stays fixed relative to robot... just some assumptions that must be true), then the center pixel address of the barcode in the image the robot takes, tells me EXACTLY what my "centering error" equals. Not a bad relationship for a rube to find. No?

[image]

**Relationship #3**
If the robot is exactly 60cm away, I get a line with a slightly different slope and Y intercept compared to the 30cm relationshop. The pink line is the 30cm line, and the green line is the 60cm line. So, if I'm exactly 60cm away, I'll know exactly how much "centering error" I exists. Both lines and equations can be found here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mulkeviown
[image]

My problem: I could get the line equation for all the possible distances (1cm, 2cm, 3cm all the way to 60cm away), then use the area of the barcode to figure out how far I am away and choose the correct line equation to find the "centering error". That would be a very manual, hard, and ugly coding solution to the problem.

I am hoping to use the two line equations and the distance equation to generate one equation where I feed the following variables:

- area of barcode (same as distance)
- x coordinate of the center point of the barcode in the image

and get the correlated "centering error" value as a distance.

Any advice on how to do this? I am hoping to not have to get all 3D geometric on this challenge (plan B) as I think I have enough data and equations to solve this challenge.

Comment: Suppose the centering error is known. What will you do with it? I ask because it seems that having the x co-ord of the barcode in the image at 300 has no error, so why not adjust trajectory until the x co-ord is at 300?

Comment: @Sal the "centering error" is what I need to know so that my robot can move to align the center of the robot with the center of the charger. Knowing this value will allow to center in a single move. Only then can I drive straight and dock. And you are correct, I can make a bunch of small motions, but that is inefficient, and ugly. Imagine parking a car... Do you want it done in 1 move (ex: stunt slide), 3 moves (typical parallel park), 10 moves (typical bad driver)? As the builder of this project, I want it to look cool when docking.

Comment: @Sal Oh, one more thing, one software will bring the robot to the charging area (ROS Navigation stack), and a separate software will dock the robot. So the drive to the charger and docking are two separate pieces of software. The step of figuring out the "centering error" is critical in the docking software. Essentially, driving the robot into docking station is not really an option as i don't have that much runway...

Comment: So by the first graph we know how much the camera zooms in or out relative to the distance. However, your second graph and third one, which talks about the X coordinates as absolute and we lack informations about them from the first. I would think we need more informations. For example, if we zoom out, does the whole XY coordinates expand from the origin of the beginning?

Comment: If answering yes to my last question, we can first compute what we would have seen if we were at a 30cm distance. Let $f$ denote the relation indicated by graph 1 and $g$ indicated by the graph 2. The $\bar x$ we would have seen at 30cm is equal to $\sqrt{\frac{A}{f(30cm)}}x$, with $A$ being the area of the barcode in camera and $x$ being the coordinate (i.e. the second input you give). The centering error should then be $g(\bar x)$.

Comment: Why you don't use "center coordinate of barcode" to correct center error?

Comment: Damn so this question was posted in 2021... I'll give as shot at it. I am amazed at how invested you are at it +1

Comment: Could you please describe what exactly is the objective? What function needs to be solved What are our knowns? The physical motivation has sort of over shadowed the mathematical problem underneath

Comment: " The amount of area occupied by the barcode in the image is correlated to the distance between the robot and the charger." Do you mean perceived area of bar code by robot or real area?

Comment: @Buraian The objective is to figure out the "centering error" for any distance value less that 60cm. At exactly 30cm I can figure it out. At exactly 60cm I can figure it out. so how do I figure out the value at any distance from 0cm to 60cm. what is that equation? That is the point here. And thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: Could you please mark the known variables in the robot diagram you've drawn

Comment: Bro, I used paint to draw a shitty image. merging that image with desmos is beyond my know-how. can you please set up a chat? I suck at computing.... I would love to answer any questions that may help you help me.

Comment: Naive comment: Assuming the robot is aligned with the charger when the camera is aligned with the charger, it seems easier to find the lengths of the left and right sides of the QR code (a trivial formula from the coordinates in your photograph) and ensure those are equal. (Generally, the longer side is closer to the camera; here for example the camera is left of the QR code because the left side of the image is one pixel longer.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang what you are saying is indeed possible, and pretty doable. I would localize robot relative to charger based on image, and then guestimate a move and move. then localize and move again.  Meaning I would move the bot a bit, check, then move again, and again. The problem there is that such an approach is not "cool". I am pretty sure I can eliminate the "centering error" in a single aligning motion.... and to do that I need an equation that gives me the "centering error" value. That is the challenge for me. Could you please help with the equation amalgamation?

Comment: Did you think about the integration of those measure functions into your cart dynamics by using a Kalman filter? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Kalman%E2%80%93Bucy_filter

Answer (score 1):

It's evident from your relationships $2$ and $3$, that the equation for the centering error, $\ ce\ $, in terms of $\ x\ $ and the distance $\ D\ $, has the form
$$
ce=m(D)(345-x)\ .
$$
without more details of the camera optics, it's impossible to know for sure what form the function $\ m\ $ takes, but it's possible that it might be given by the simple geometry illustrated in the figure below.  This would give
$$
\frac{ce}{D+d}=\frac{345-x}{e}\ ,
$$
or
$$
m(D)=\frac{D+d}{e}\ .
$$
Your relationships $2$ and $3$ then give
$$
m(30)=\frac{30+d}{e}=0.086\\
m(60)=\frac{60+d}{e}=0.125\ ,
$$
which you can solve for $\ e\ $ and $\ d\ $:
$$
e=\frac{10}{0.013}\\
d=\frac{0.125\times10}{0.013}-60\approx36.15\ ,
$$
thus giving
$$
ce=0.0013(D+36.15)(345-x)
$$
as the equation for $\ ce\ $ in terms of $\ x\ $ and $\ D\ $.  The fact that $\ e\ $ turns out to be much larger than $\ D+d\ $ for the values of $\ D\ $ you're interested in, makes me doubt that the equation's likely  to be helpful. Are you able to check whether it actually works?

I don't see how you could possibly do what you want *unless* you can get a formula for $\ m(D)\ $, or at least one which gives a sufficiently close approximation to it.  If you assume $\ m(D)\ $ to be an affine function of $\ D\ $ (that is, it has the form $\ m(D)=$$\,aD+b\ $), then your relationships $2$ and $3$ imply that it *must* be given by the formula above—that is, $\ M(D)=$$\,0.0013(D+36.15)\ $. If you were to assume that $\ m(D)\ $ is a polynomial of higher degree in $\ D\ $, you would need more relationships of the same form as $2$ and $3$ to pin down the the polynomial's coefficients.  For a polynomial of degree $\ n\ $ you would have to obtain such relationships for at least $\ n+1\ $ different values of $\ D\ $.

[image]

Comment: @Ionza could you please color code your letters in the diagram you provided as part of your answer? I am trying to make sure I understand which label corresponds to which distance. Let's assume the camera is in the middle of the robot (middle of X and Y coordinate) Thanks.

Comment: @Mike I have now changed the diagram.  I have also corrected one copying error and changed the orientation of the X-Y coordinate system I had originally used.  Your relationships $2$ and $3$ tell us that the centring error is $0$ when $\ x=345\ $, which means that the origin of the coordinate system is either $345$  X-units to the left or the same distance to the right of the centre line.  I am now assuming that it's on the left, and that points to its right will have a positive X coordinate.